# Run Time Error "424" Object Required / Ms Access VBA ./ Objects are declared but still the error Could some one spot the error?

Tags: ms-access, vba

Private Sub method3_Click()

```
Dim conn1 As ADODB.Connection
Dim recSet As ADODB.Recordset

mySQL = "Select * from Contact"
Set conn1 = New ADODB.Connection
conn1.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
```

'ERROR WHEN PROGRAM REACHES THE LINE BELOW

```
conn1.Open (Server.Mappath("G:\Data\StudentDB.accDB"))

 Set recSet = New ADODB.Recordset
 recSet.Open mySQL, conn1, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

     mobile = recSet.Field(3)
 recSet.Close
 conn1.Close

Set conn = Nothing
Set recSet = Nothing
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1):

`Server` is not defined at that exact line.
You can use `SET Conn1 = CurrentProject.Connection` to avoid having to create a new connection from scratch.